# HTTPS enabled for 54.x.x.x but not for 54.x.x.x:8080 any help please?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I have an nginx server running on 54.x.x.x and I have jenkins that is also running on nginx on 54.x.x.x:8080.
I set an SSL certification on 54.x.x.x , but when it goes to **54.x.x.x:8080** (jenkins) there is no https over there and that's the problem! i need the https enabled for jenkins ..
(NB we do not have domain name , just these ip addresses)
Any help please!

Comment: It is impossible to tell what you are doing without seeing your configuration. In general - the certificate configuration you have for one virtual host will not magically propagate to another so you need to have the certificates explicitly configured for 8080 the same as you do with 443. But note you cannot have port 8080 available for both HTTP and HTTPS at the same time.

Comment: @amfs paste the config else we can't handle this question i flag this question for poor quality

Comment: Most often one configures reverse proxy in nginx that proxies requests to Jenkins. Jenkins is changed so that it only listens to localhost.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  thank you all guys! actually i solved the problem by redirecting all trafic from :8080 to :80. With this, I think I'll be able to enable https directly